# Looping through (Name) of Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

My question is actually quite simple but I can't find a solution.
I have a lot of sheets with different names that can be modified by the user. I've given to each of those sheets a background name, so for my first two sheets, their names in my VBA project look like this:

[image]

The fact is, I want to do a macro to loop through all those particular Sheets (I have 14 of them), and I don't want to Loop through the other ones that I use for different things, like this one:

[image]

It is easy to loop through my Sheets using the names that can be modified by the user ("General" et "Heritage" in my example). Nevertheless, I want the user to be able to modify this name whenever he wants, and if he does that, my macros will not recognize the new name of the sheet. It is really important for me that the user doesn't have to push a button or use a different textbox to rename his sheet, I don't want to avoid the problem this way.

What I want is to be able to loop through the background name (S1 and S2 in my example), doing something like that (I know that the following code isn't good, but it is just to give you an example):

```
Sub Example1()

Dim wksht As Worksheet

For i = 1 To 14
    Set wksht = "S" & i
    wksht.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
Next i

End Sub
```

I know that the following code works for 1 sheet:

```
Sub Example2()

Dim wksht As Worksheet
Set wksht = S1
wksht.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is S1 in my previous code isn't a string, so I can't loop using "S" & i. Is there a solution to my problem ?

Comment: use the CodeName of the worksheet object to check for the names you have given them: if  wksht.CodeName = "S1" then ... end if

Comment: Thanks ! That is indeed the CodeName that I was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the sheet code name, so can do something like this. By the way, this will match S followed by a single digit which may or may not be sufficient for your needs. (By the way, it's 'through', not 'threw'.)

```
Sub Example1()

Dim wksht As Worksheet

For Each wksht In Worksheets
    If wksht.CodeName Like "S#" Then
        'do something
    End If
Next wksht

End Sub
```

Comment: My pleasure, and no need to apologise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, there does not appear a way to reference sheets based on their codename string, however,  you can get the codename as a string from a sheet.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws_temp As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For i = 1 To 4
        For Each ws_temp In wb.Sheets
            If ws_temp.CodeName = "S" & i Then
                Set ws = ws_temp
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print ws.Name & " " & ws.CodeName
    Next

End Sub
```

This code will march through all of the S# sheets in order, and allow you to work with each one as ws.